# The "Add to cart" button allows me to add more items to the cart than there are in the inventory

Tags: commerce

I am trying to work on a Drupal 8 commerce site which was built by someone else. I have not used the *Commerce Core* module in the past.

Product variation has stock field where I enter total inventory I have. On the product page, I can still add more units to the cart than the inventory I have.

However, I get an error stating that "We do not have xx items in stock." but the item are still added to the cart. For example, I have 10 in stock but I can add 20 items to the cart even I get the error  "We do not have 20 items in stock." When I click on *Add to cart*, other 20 items get added to cart with the same error message.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I should not be able to add more units to the cart than the inventory contains, even if I click on *Add to Cart* multiple times.

Can you please tell me how to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you looked 8n the Commerce stock issue que for similar issues?

Comment: No, I did not see any similar issue listed there.